# PHP's return syntax and semantics

Tags: php

What's the difference between two function A,F? 
 sorry for using mysql instead of mysqli or PDO

```
function A ($B){

    if($result = mysql_query("SELECT C FROM D WHERE E")) 
    {
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
         return  $text = $row['C'];
        }
        return 0;
    }

return 0;
}
```

and this one:

```
function F ($G){

        if($result = mysql_query("SELECT C FROM D WHERE E")) 
        {
            if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
             return  $row['C'];
            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The end result in both cases is the same (as they are now), since both functions will return the value of column `C` if queries are successful and return a result.

On the first example `A` will also return `0` if the query is successful but no results are returned hence if you modify it as:

```
function A ($B){

    if($result = mysql_query("SELECT C FROM D WHERE E")) 
    {
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            return  $text = $row['C'];
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

if the returned value is `0` you'll know the query was successfull but if the return value was `1` it will mean the query execution failed. That is if `C` does not contain the values `0` or `1` where in that case you wouldn't really be sure on whether the returned `0` or `1` is the return value of column `C` or the function's actual return statement

**UPDATE**

To distinguish between the two you could return `false` if something has failed:

```
 return false;
```

and then check if the return value of the function is really false:

```
if(A() === false)
{
     // something went wrong, do something else
}
```

*Note*: See the `===`, it makes sure that the equality check only checks for boolean value `false` and that string `"false"` or values `0` or `'0'` are not classified as `false`

Comment: is it possible to have a function with 2 result? 
in this case , if query is successful , 0 and $text is returning?